# How to properly write down the general term of this sequence of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, notation

Consider the following sequence of matrices: $A_n\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, defined as

$$A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \text{etc.}$$

> What is a proper, **crystal clear**, way of writting down the general term $A_n$ of this sequence?

I have tried the following, but am only half satisfied with it and I am wondering if there is smarter/neater way:
$$A_n=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots& 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots &  \vdots\\ \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots &0 \\
 0 &\cdots &\cdots & 0 & 1\\ 1 &0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A_n=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots& 0& 0 \\ 
 0&0&1&\cdots&0& 0\\
 %\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots&  \vdots\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots &  &  \vdots&  \vdots\\ 
 %\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & & \ddots &   \vdots\\ 
 %\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots &0 \\
 0 &0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 1 &0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Do these matrices have a particular standard name? I think they are the adjacency matrices of the cyclic directed path on a graph of $n$ nodes, but I am not sure this fully characterize them.

*Disclaimer:* I don't think this question belongs to Tex.SE as it about how to best convey a mathematical idea and not about how to type a matrix in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write this (after your first few examples):

In general, 
$$
a^n_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 & j \equiv i+1 \pmod n \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases},
$$
so that $A^n$ is the directed adjacency matrix of a directed cycle of $n$ nodes, or, informally, $A^n$ is $n \times n$, has ones above the diagonal, and in the lower left corner.

Of course, you may choose not to use $A^n$ to indicate the $n$th matrix; I was merely giving an example of a possible notation.

I suppose you could also describe it as a particular Toeplitz matrix, but I'm not sure (depending on context) whether that'd be informative or not. A more compact way would be to say that it's a "circulant matrix on the vector $e_2 \in \Bbb R^n$," but that just sends the reader off to look up "circulant matrix," unless that's an idea that's already in context.

Comment: I thought a writing directly the expression for the entries. But I really would like to have a picture of the matrix. Particularly important is that the reader catches in a milisecond that the diagonal entries are all $0$. Furthermore, the expected readers (and myself) are not particularly used to work with modulo operations. Not that they don't know it, just that it requires some (unnecessary?) effort to parse the expression.

Comment: You could make three cases: $j = i + 1; i = n, j = 1; else$, and that'd remove the "mod". And your pictures are clearly valuable for communicating the idea. But a formula of some kind, so that the confused reader can confirm or deny a generalized conjecture from the visual examples, is also nice to have.

Comment: Toeplitz is a cool idea as well, and personally, is more efficient than a "modulo" definition, but as you said, this just sends the reader to google :D.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be telegraphic in your explanation? Sometimes it's worth saying things 2 or 3 ways. :)

Comment: Good point!, perhaps you are right. I can just put one of my picture and write down the expression as you did. Sounds like the most efficient and clear way.

Comment: There is no big reasons for that. Especially if I can afford (in terms of space) to write down such a matrix, then I can afford to repeat the definition :). Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define $A_n$ as the permutation matrix associated to the permutation $\pi = (1\;2\;3\;\dots\;n)$, written in cycle notation.

But to meet the standard of "crystal clear", we should probably clarify that this is the version of the matrix that acts on a vector $\mathbf x$ by permuting is entries according to $\pi$ (the *column representation* of $\pi$, as defined [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Definition)).

Another idea is to define $A_n$ as the matrix with columns $\mathbf e_n, \mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \dots, \mathbf e_{n-1}$, where $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \dots, \mathbf e_n$ are the standard basis vectors. (The Wikipedia article linked to above uses this notation for row vectors, but using it for column vectors is more conventional.)

Answer (score 1):

[Charlie Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Royal_Johnson) also calls these matrices the *basic [circulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)* because 
$$A_n = \text{circ}(0,1,0,\dots,0) = \begin{bmatrix} e_2^\top \\ e_3^\top \\ \vdots \\e_n^\top \\ e_1^\top \end{bmatrix}.$$ 
Consequently, if $F_n$ denotes the $n$-by-$n$ *[discrete Fourier transform matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)*, then
$$A_n = F_n \text{diag}(1,\omega_n,\dots, \omega_n^{n-1})F^*_n,$$
in which $\omega_n := \exp(2\pi\textrm{i}/n)$.